# Converting SDP in standard form to inequality form

Tags: convex-optimization, duality-theorems, semidefinite-programming

I want to convert semidefinite program

min $tr(XY)$ subject to

$X \succeq 0$, $tr(XA_i)+c_i = 0$) where  matrices $A_i, Y$ and vector $c_i$ are given

into the form with matrix inequalities that looks like this:

min $a^Tb$ subject to:

$z_1D_1 +z_2D_2 +...+ z_nD_n \preceq F$

I need the second form because I need to implement subgradient  method for SDP problem. And I know how to do this with second form, I can see that gradient there is simply $a^T$ and if it is not feasible I will project it.

But in the first form I dont know how to do subgradient method. I googled a lot how to trasnform standard form into inequalitites, but everyone shows only how to transform inequalities into standard form and not vice versa.

Comment: they are duals, so just form the dual

Comment: @LinAlg indeed they are duals, but the problems are not identical. As far as I know there could be duality gap between these two problems. What I am looking for is equivalent formulation of SDP as a matrix inequality, so that solutions are exactly same

Comment: @LinAlg I need to apply subgradient method for SDP and for its dual and compare results. I have already applied subgradient method when in inequality form and now I need to use subgradient method for SDP in standard form, which I don't know how to do. So I decided to reformulate standard form into matrix inequality and apply the same technique I did for initial problem

Comment: If Slater's condition is satisfied, then you can be sure that strong duality will hold.  If not, there could very well be a duality gap.  You can apply (projected) subgradient methods to both the primal and dual problems as an exercise, but this isn't a very practical thing to do.  You can also "dualize" the first problem to get the second problem by writing $X$ as a linear combination of basis matrices $E_{i,j}$ but this is also terribly impractical.  You haven't provided sufficient context to explain what you're trying to do exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let vec be the operator that takes a matrix and stacks all columns into a single vector. The objective is vec$(Y)^T$vec$(X)$, and the constraints are equivalent to:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
\text{vec}(A_1)^T \text{vec}(X) & \\
0    & -\text{vec}(A_1)^T \text{vec}(X) & \\
0    & 0    & \ddots \\
0    & 0    & 0       & \text{vec}(A_m)^T \text{vec}(X) \\
0    & 0    & 0       & 0    & -\text{vec}(A_m)^T \text{vec}(X) \\
0    & 0    & 0       & 0    & 0     & X
\end{pmatrix}
\succeq
\begin{pmatrix}
-c_1 \\
c_1 \\
\vdots \\
-c_m \\
c_m \\
0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The omitted elements above the diagonal are all 0. Since the constraints are linear in the elements of $X$, you can take $z = \text{vec}(X)$ and construct $n^2$ matrices $D_i$ of size $(n+m)\times(n+m)$ each.

Comment: How can $X\succeq 0$  be represented with $z:=\textrm{vec}(X)$?

Comment: @Teodorism there is no $X \succeq 0$ in the second form. If you want to add it, you need to undo the vectorize operator (which is a linear operator).